# quotient topology in compact hausdorff space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X is compact hausdorff space and A is a subset of X. Show that X/A is Hausdorff ,when A is closed. I have no idea how to proof it. Can you give me a clue?

Comment: Basically, you need to separate $A$ and $x\in X\setminus A$ by open sets in $X$.

Comment: It is not X\A but X/A (quotient topology)

Comment: No, I mean $X\setminus A$. That separation is then pushed down to $X/A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Compact Hausdorff space is regular (even normal).

Answer (score 0):

Split this into cases. Consider the case where $[x],[y] \in [X \setminus A]$, and then the case where $[x] \in [X \setminus A]$, $[y] \in [A]$.